# How to prevent Maxima tex1 from wrapping its output?

Tags: maxima

I invoked Maxima `tex1` from within a batch script as follows:

```
maxima --very-quiet -r "tex1(solve(8*x^2+7*x+5));" | grep -v false > output.txt
```

and I got the `output.txt` as follows:

```
 \left[ x=-{{\sqrt{111}\,i+7}\over{16}} , x={{\sqrt{111}\,i-7}\over{16}} \righ\
t]
```

that is not valid as a (La)TeX input file.

How to prevent Maxima `tex1` from wrapping its output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, unfortunately, hard coded into Maxima. A way to solve this problem is to edit the function myprinc located in the file `maxima/src/mactex.lisp`. There is a `cond` form that has a 70. written there, it should read linel instead of 70.  If you recompile maxima after making this change then the following will work:

```
maxima --very-quiet -r "linel: 1000$ tex1(solve(8*x^2+7*x+5));" | grep -v false > output.txt
```

Anyway, I'll send a patch to the Maxima list ASAP so that future versions of the program won't have this shortcoming.

Comment: @jmbr: I also get an error when invoking `tex1(expand((x+y+z)^3));` :-(

Comment: @xport: works fine for me but I'm using the latest Git version of Maxima (that may be the reason).

Comment: @xport: http://paste.lisp.org/display/122568  I already sent a small patch to the Maxima list, let's see what the developers have to say.

Comment: Did the error appear after modifying the source code? If yes, then wait until the developers say something about my patch. Otherwise do post the error message there. I just copy and pasted the output.

Comment: @xport: In that case, yes, do fill a bug report. You can write bug_report(); inside Maxima and that will point you to the bug tracker. As for the problem copying and pasting from wxMaxima, I don't know, I use Maxima inside Emacs but I guess you could invoke Maxima in the console and copy and paste from there. Sorry that I can't help you more with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late reply.

Instead of

tex1(solve(8*x^2+7*x+5));

write:

?princ(tex1(solve(8*x^2+7*x+5)))$

The problem is that the string returned by tex1 is being printed by the display formatter (the same function which would print the string if you were using Maxima in an interactive session). The display formatter breaks strings at linel characters (default = 79) and inserts a backslash. Instead for your purposes you want to evade the display formatter entirely, so you print the string with ?princ (a Lisp function to just print the string) and terminate the input with "$" instead of ";" to tell Maxima not to call the display formatter.

Note that the hard-coded constant 70 in MYPRINC doesn't come into play here. MYPRINC is not called in the example given.